# github actions copy updates to azure app service

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a NodeJS app that I have a workflow that on push installs all the dependencies and deploys the app to the app service.

I was wondering is there a way of just copying the updated files from GitHub to the app service, rather than rebuilding the whole app and redeploying?

Comment: How do you compile your app? Do you use ncc? Does packaging in your case just mean copying some files? Why do you want to copy only some files?

Comment: Currently I use a workflow to build and deploy the application to the app service. It is a express web app. There is no build process needed to run the app. So i was hoping say i change one of my internal js files, that it just copies that file across to the app service to replace.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at rsync?